# Flutter MatrixGestureDetector - Minimum and maximum scale

Tags: flutter, dart, zooming, scale

My question essentially duplicates the previously asked question: [Flutter: How to set a max/min scale using matrix_gesture_detector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60858334/flutter-how-to-set-a-max-min-scale-using-matrix-gesture-detector)

I have a MatrixGestureDetector:

```
  MatrixGestureDetector(
    onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
      setState(() {
        transform = m;
      });
    },
    child: Transform(
      transform: transform,
      child: Image.asset("assets/maps/map.gif"),
    ),
  ),
```

The picture can be zoomed in and out indefinitely, but I want to limit the minimum and maximum scale.

The solution suggested in the link above is not correct for me. The scale is really limited, but when it reaches its limits, gestures start to be handled incorrectly. The picture starts moving very quickly when you try to zoom in or out when the limits are reached.

Is there any solution to this problem? Maybe there are other packages to solve my problem? PhotoViev did not satisfy me for the reason described here: [Flutter PhotoView - Rotation about the point between the fingers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207173/flutter-photoview-rotation-about-the-point-between-the-fingers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter announced a new version(1.20) and it came with a new widget called `InteractiveViewer`.

You can use the `InteractiveViewer` to achieve what you want by setting a `minScale` and `maxScale`.

> This release introduces a new widget, the `InteractiveViewer`. The `InteractiveViewer` is designed for building common kinds of interactivity into your app, like pan, zoom, and drag ’n’ drop

Read more about the release here: [Flutter 1.20 Release notes](https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-flutter-1-20-2aaf68c89c75)

I added a demo:

NOTE: You can only use this widget if you have upgraded to the latest `Flutter version` (1.20)

```
class ZoomImage extends StatelessWidget {

  final transformationController = TransformationController();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: InteractiveViewer(
        transformationController: transformationController,
        onInteractionEnd: (details) {
          setState(() {
            // unzoom when interaction has ended
            transformationController.toScene(Offset.zero);
          });
        },
        // set the boundary margin for the image 
        boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        // set min scale here
        minScale: 0.1,
        // set maximum scall here
        maxScale: 1.6,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
          child: Image.asset('assets/maps/map.gif'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does InteractiveViewer support rotation gestures? I need them.

Comment: I haven't tried it with the rotation gestures, but since it supports most gestures listed above, rotation should be a plus too.

Comment: Unfortunately, the rotation has not yet been implemented https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57698

Comment: Oops :( , I guess my answer answered your question? You can mark as correct if it does.

Comment: Okay. I will wait for InteractiveViewer updates. Thank you!

Comment: setState() in a StatelessWidget??